# Why is the error, dd: /dev/rdisk1bs=1m: Operation not supported, popping up while trying to instal ubuntu on usb?

Tags: command-line, usb, usb-drive

I am trying to install ubuntu onto my flash drive using the instructions from this website: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx.

After step 8, the terminal asks for my password, which it accepts and then pops up with this error message:

```
dd: /dev/rdisk1bs=1m: Operation not supported.
```

I have also tried making the last m in that statement capital and then the system does not ask me for my password but the error message still pops up. What is happening and why?

Comment: There should be a space between `/dev/rdisk1` and `bs`. If that's not the **typo** you've done while issuing that `dd` but only here, you can [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/edit) so that no confusion arise.

Comment: Hmm... Try to erase all data on USB(via terminal or via Disk Utility)

Answer (score 74):

If you clicked the little eject icon in the Finder, this will unmount *and* eject the usb drive, which will give the error you saw.  You want to umount only.

Unmounting can be done in Apple's Disk Utility using the *Unmount* button (in toolbar next to *Eject*), or it can be done as [Marcel answers below](https://askubuntu.com/a/354713/11052) from the commandline.

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. It would be helpful to OP if you can explain your answer in more details.

Comment: Unmount failed for /dev/rdisk3

Comment: You rox!! Thank you! I was having difficulties to find the solution, thank you very much! :)

Comment: this is correct. Using the "umount" command also ejects the disk (!)

Answer (score 8):

If the above does not help (as it did for me), try

```
sudo diskutil umountDisk /dev/diskN
```

That did the trick for me.

Comment: Some explanation?

Answer (score 7):

If the disk is still mounted, you'll get a 'resource busy' error. If it's been ejected, you'll get the 'Operation not supported' error. You need to go into disk utility and *UNMOUNT* the partitions on the drive but do not *EJECT* the destination drive. Hope this helps as it can get kinda frustrating and the errors aren't always particularly helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I've also had a similar problem while using the correct syntax (i.e. `dd bs=1m if=source.img of=/dev/rdisk1`).

A reboot seemed to fix my issue, despite several attempts with a command that had worked previously while restoring a different image.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

i had to unmount then run:

`sudo dd if=image.img of=/dev/disk1s1 bs=512k`

Comment: Strange, even for me Mac OS insisted on `bs=512k`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The correct command is `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (Replacing N with the disk number you found by running `diskutil list`)

The space between rdiskN and bs=1m is not clear in the [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) because of the way the text wraps.

Answer (score 1):

of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m

I didnt realize my first time that the N is still a variable for the disk number you found when running diskutil list

Answer (score 0):

As [DreadPirate said](https://askubuntu.com/a/312631/510033), you probably have to unmount every single partition of the usb drive first. If no other command listed here works, try the following:

```
df -h
```

will return the currently mounted partitions. Find the ones belong to your thumb drive and use

```
sudo umount /dev/disk1sX
```

for each one of them, where 0 < X <= number of partitions on the usb drive (found after running the first command).

Comment: I had to use `sudo diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskNsX`

Comment: Well that's what @DreadPirate suggested and it's fine. All I am saying is if that does not work, try my suggestion. It works on my machine.